# change the comment time output to: X time ago instead of actual date and time

Tags: functions, date-time, comments, comment-meta

```
<?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?>
```

Above is the default code that exists for comments.php in the WP Core.

This will produce an Output like this:

[image]

> October 1, 2017 at 6:58 am

But I want something like this →

> Posted: 11 Months ago

or

> Posted 3 days Back

or

> Posted 23 hours back

Is it possible to collaborate thse two:

```
get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()
```

to get the above-mentioned effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff

So this should do exactly what you need:

```
 <?php printf( _x( '%s ago', '%s = human-readable time difference', 'your-text-domain' ), human_time_diff( get_comment_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Can you or someone help me to improve the title? so that it can be searchable in future?

Comment: Something like: "Change time output to: X time ago"

Comment: I have changed the title as per your suggestions sir. Thanks for your help. accepted your answer.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help you!

Comment: cheers! and all the best on this website.